# Table field that holds row count from another table

Tags: sql, database

I have a field where I want to store the number of certain rows from another table. I have been incrementing this value when the rows are created, but feel this is probably not the best way. THen again I dont think that doing "count" on the table in question every time makes sense either. what is best approach?

EDIT:
Count is filtered

Comment: This field that stores the number is in a different table? Do you update it manually every time a row is added? What is the purpose of storing the number of rows instead of querying for the number of rows each time you need the number?

Comment: @kevin, yes i manually i++ and update the cell. i am afraid that querying the number of rows each time would be too expensive. or is it?

Comment: You still are doing a query to grab the count that is stored. A count(*) query is not expensive enough to worry about.

Comment: the query is not total rows in table, its specified rows. ie # rows with price=100

Comment: @zsharp: Would you specify RDBMS?

Comment: The fact that you're not sure if it's too expensive or not is a big red flag. Run some tests, make sure that your table(s) are indexed properly. Don't try to optimize a database for performance when you don't even know what the performance is. It's premature and just going to cause you big headaches

Answer (score 2):

Create an *INSERT* **trigger** to increment a product count.

[image]

Here is the code

```
create table Products ( ID int identity primary key )
GO
create table ProductCounter ( ProductCount int not null default 0 )
GO
insert ProductCounter default values
GO
create trigger trgIncrementProductCount
on Products
after insert
as
begin
    update  ProductCounter
    set ProductCount = ProductCount + 1
end
GO

insert Products default values
insert Products default values
select * from ProductCounter

insert Products default values
insert Products default values
select * from ProductCounter
```

Answer (score 1):

If its sql server, you could make triggers for insert and delete to increment/decrement the value.

Or you could make a view for it.

Or, as i would do, simply do the count(*) every time, unless its a huge table.

Comment: The size of the table shouldn't matter when doing an unfiltered count.

Comment: Although it appears to be a filtered count: "store the number of *certain* rows". So a WHERE clause would be involved and performance could be an issue.

Comment: Interestingly, i have actually seen an unfiltered count(*) take a long time in the past, with an enormous table (30mil rows). Can't remember how long, but it was at least few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If the value you're looking for is the count of rows from the first table, that would be a far less expensive operation than the overhead of insterting/updating a second table and then querying the value out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Note this is a specific Sql Server answer, first off I'm not sure if

```
select count(*) from table
```

really does a full table scan, the execution plan says that it does. Iff, that is true then you can lookup the number of rows in a table using the system tables and that will be faster especially on a large table.

```
select rowcnt from sysindexes
inner join sysobjects on sysobjects.id = sysindexes.id
where xtype='U'
and sysobjects.name = 'YourTableName'
and indid = 0
```

I know this relies on system tables that may change, but these haven't for the last decade, it also relies on your table having a primary key. So rather than storing the number of rows you have a fast but nasty lookup.

Comment: But he will need a filtered count, as in the comment that was added later, "# rows with price=100." So it looks as if he'll need a regular COUNT() query.

Comment: count(*) does a table scan on SQL Server?  Now, that's just messed up.  You'd think it'd be smart enough to count the number of entries in the primary key's index.

Answer (score 1):

While you never would want to store a calculated value in a database in an ideal world, it's often necessary down here in the mud and muck of the real world.

So Chris's suggestion of a trigger is your best bet. You may have to requery the count after each trigger invocation, since it may not always be possible to know how many rows were inserted or deleted (depending on RDBMS), and you may need multiple queries if there's a chance that more than one of your counts could be affected by a single INSERT or DELETE statement.

And, since you're also counting specific rows, you'll also need an UPDATE trigger, in case one of the values your count filters on is changed.

So, the trigger or triggers (you may be able to package it all into a single INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE trigger) could get pretty complicated.

Answer (score 1):

How often is this row count needed?  Is it possible to run something like a cron to update every few hours?  Simple SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Table WHERE...yada yada. It would not rely on the additional update after each query.

Just a ponderance...