# MySQL: Sort items by category count

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I currently use the following query which works perfectly:

```
SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `id` IN 
    (SELECT `item_id` FROM `categories_items` 
     WHERE `category_id` IN (1, 2) GROUP BY `item_id` 
     HAVING COUNT(`item_id`) = 2);
```

It selects all the items that are in all the selected (checkboxes) categories.

The problem is that most items are in many categories and a few items are only in two categories and when I only check those two, I still get a list of hundreds of items, making it nearly impossible to find the items that are in few categories.

My first idea was to add an `ORDER BY "number_of_total_categories_that_the_selected_item_is_in" ASC` somewhere in the query, but since I even got help with the current one and there would probably be a lot of calculations/subqueries for it to work, I thought of an extra column in the `items` table that would hold the number of categories it's in!

- Is it possible to add an effective ORDER BY clause to the query and if so, what would it look like?
- Do you have any other ideas? Would "an inverted" foreign key solution work here? Not a chance, right? :p

If not, all I can think of is to manually update a `category_count` column in `items` whenever it's needed.

Edit: [Table field that holds row count from another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680083/table-field-that-holds-row-count-from-another-table) looks interesting, but I have no idea whether it would work in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `join` rather than `in`.  The following query filters for items that only have the two categories you want.  It also counts the total number of categories, which can be used for the `order by`:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM `items` i JOIN
       (SELECT `item_id`, COUNT(*) as cnt
        FROM `categories_items` 
        WHERE `category_id` IN (1, 2)
        GROUP BY `item_id` 
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN category_id IN (1, 2) THEN category_id END) = 2
       ) c
       ON i.id = c.item_id
ORDER BY cnt ASC;
```

EDIT:

If you want to count *all* the categories, then get rid of the `where`.  It is not really doing anything:

```
SELECT i.*
FROM `items` i JOIN
       (SELECT `item_id`, COUNT(*) as cnt
        FROM `categories_items` 
        GROUP BY `item_id` 
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN category_id IN (1, 2) THEN category_id END) = 2
       ) c
       ON i.id = c.item_id
ORDER BY cnt ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The SELECT works, but not the ORDER BY. I think the issue is that the query counts the selected categories instead of all that each item is in.

Comment: After a few tests, this seems to work perfectly! I appreciate it a lot.